# Head command with n lines given input in shell script

Tags: bash, sh

I’m absolute beginner and I started learning commands a while ago! I want **num** as input from user , I’ll write like

```
#!/bin/bash  
read num  
read y  
head -n $num $y
```

where **num** is 5 and **y** is txt file
It shows error as head:invalid number of lines:’5\r’
But instead of **$num** head -n 5 $y is working fine in compiler!
Could someone help with this?

Comment: Replace `#!/bash/bin` with `#!/bin/bash`.

Comment: Welcome to SO, I believe you have copied script some Windows to *Nix system. That `3\r` tells that. So you could run command like `tr -d '\r' < your_script > temp && mv temp your_script` and then try to run your script.

Comment: Or just `dos2unix` on it.

Comment: It sounds like num is being set to $'3\r', so dos2unix or tr -d won't fix it. OP how are you running your script (`./script` or `bash script`) and where (cygwin or git bash or wsl)?

Comment: @stonewareslord it is .sh file and online compiler

Comment: @stonewareslord the 3\r probably comes from the `head` command when there's a \r after $y